# C++ - Hash map implementation using smart pointers

Tags: c++, hash-map, pointers

I am trying a simple Hash Map implementation in c++. I have used [this](https://medium.com/@aozturk/simple-hash-map-hash-table-implementation-in-c-931965904250) and [this](http://www.algolist.net/Data_structures/Hash_table/Simple_example) as reference. The implemented design uses a class `HashEntry` to manage individual key-value pair. The class `HashMap` handles the map itself. The map has functions to insert(`put`) a key-value pair, to retrieve(`get`) value based on a key and to erase(`erase`) a key-value pair. It also keeps track of its `size` and `capacity`. Here is the commented code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <cstddef>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <climits>

// Class for individual entries of key-value pair
class HashEntry
{
    int key_v;
    int val_v;
    // The smart pointer to handle multiple keys with same hash value.
    // This will be used to create a linkedlist.
    std::shared_ptr<HashEntry> next_v;
public:
    HashEntry(int key, int val) : key_v{key}, val_v{val}
    {}

    int key() const
    {
        return key_v;
    }

    int val() const
    {
        return val_v;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<HashEntry> next() const
    {
        return next_v;
    }

    void set_val(int val)
    {
        val_v = val;
    }

    void set_next(std::shared_ptr<HashEntry> next)
    {
        next_v = next;
    }
};

// Class for the Hash Map
class HashMap
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<HashEntry>> map_v;
    std::size_t capacity_v{0};
    std::size_t size_v{0};
public:
    HashMap(std::size_t);
    std::size_t hash_func(int);
    std::size_t size() const;
    void put(int, int);
    int get(int);
    bool erase(int);
};

HashMap::HashMap(std::size_t capacity)
{
    capacity_v = capacity;
    map_v.resize(capacity_v);
}

// The hashing function
std::size_t HashMap::hash_func(int key)
{
    return key % capacity_v;
}

std::size_t HashMap::size() const
{
    return size_v;
}

// The function to insert key-value pair
void HashMap::put(int key, int val)
{
    // If capacity is reached, throw exception
    if(size_v == capacity_v)
    {
        throw std::length_error{"Capacity exceeded!\n"};
    }
    std::size_t hash_value = hash_func(key);
    // If the hash_value has never been set before, use that space
    // for key-value pair. Otherwise, add to the list.
    if(map_v[hash_value] == nullptr)
    {
        map_v[hash_value] = std::make_shared<HashEntry>(key, val);
    }
    else
    {
        auto node = map_v[hash_value];
        std::shared_ptr<HashEntry> pre = nullptr;
        while(node)
        {
            if(node->key() == key)
            {
                node->set_val(val);
                return;
            }
            pre = node;
            node = node->next();
        }
        pre->set_next(std::make_shared<HashEntry>(key, val));
    }
    size_v++;
}

// Retrieve value based on key
int HashMap::get(int key)
{
    auto hash_value = hash_func(key);
    auto node = map_v[hash_value];
    // If node is not set, nothing to retrieve.
    // Otherwise, check the key and if required, the associated list.
    // If not found, report the issue.
    if(node == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "Key not found! Returning INT_MIN for: " << key << "\n";
        return INT_MIN;
    }
    if(node->next() == nullptr && node->key() == key)
    {
        return node->val();
    }
    else
    {
        while(node)
        {
            if(node->key() == key)
            {
                return node->val();
            }
            node = node->next();
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Key not found! Returning INT_MIN for: " << key << "\n";
    return INT_MIN;
}

// Remove key-value pair based on key
bool HashMap::erase(int key)
{
    auto hash_value = hash_func(key);
    // If no value is set against hash value, there is nothing to erase.
    // Otherwise, check if keys match and if yes, proceed to erase.
    // Otherwise, check the list for a match and if there is a match,
    // proceed to erase.
    // Otherwise, return false.
    if(map_v[hash_value] == nullptr)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if(map_v[hash_value]->key() == key)
    {
        map_v[hash_value] = map_v[hash_value]->next();
        size_v--;
        return true;
    }
    else if(map_v[hash_value]->next())
    {
        auto pre = map_v[hash_value];
        auto node = map_v[hash_value]->next();
        while(node)
        {
            if(node->key() == key)
            {
                pre->set_next(node->next());
                size_v--;
                return true;
            }
            pre = node;
            node = node->next();
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    HashMap hm1{10};
    std::cout << "Size: " << hm1.size() << "\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        hm1.put(i, i + 10);
    }

    std::cout << "Size: " << hm1.size() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Get: " << hm1.get(6) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Erase: " << std::boolalpha << hm1.erase(6) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Size: " << hm1.size() << "\n";
    // Check the output of get() after key is erased
    std::cout << "Get: " << hm1.get(6) << "\n";
    // Try adding a key which will have same hash_value as another key
    // Also try retrieving both keys
    hm1.put(15, 25);
    std::cout << "Size: " << hm1.size() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Get: " << hm1.get(15) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Get: " << hm1.get(5) << "\n";
    // Erase a pair existing in the list and see how all keys in the list behave.
    std::cout << "Erase: " << std::boolalpha << hm1.erase(5) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Size: " << hm1.size() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Get: " << hm1.get(5) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Get: " << hm1.get(15) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

**Questions:**

1) Is the implementation correct for an open hashing (closed addressing) hash map?

2) The function `get` returns an `INT_MIN` if it has no other choice. The other possible ways to handle this scenario could be using `std::optional`, throw an exception, change the function to not return anything, or return a bool. Is there any other smarter/ more elegant way?

3) Any better suggestions for `hash_func`. Is there any good reading material on how to select a good hashing function or is it just a matter of experience?

If possible, kindly provide general reviews and suggestions. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I read both your reference implementers. They look more like Java that has been literally translated to C++. Though it may work neither of these are very good implementations and as such yours suffers from the same problems.

### Design

#### Design of Hash

Your hash seems to have a limit on the number of elements.

```
if(size_v == capacity_v)
{
    throw std::length_error{"Capacity exceeded!\n"};
}
```

But there does not seem to be a need for this. Each bucket in the hash is basically a list of linked elements. So you can store as many members as you like per list. So there really is no need for a size.

Hashing function are hard to write. The version you use can be used as a reasonable one but under a few conditions. The main one is that the value you use to diveide by (and thus the number of buckets) should be a prime number.

```
std::size_t HashMap::hash_func(int key)
{
    return key % capacity_v;  // here capacity should be prime.
}                             // This will give you a much larger chance of 
                              // of not creating some pattern and using some
                              // buckets more than others.
```

I know this does not sound important but there is some significant maths done on this problem (make this prime it will save you a lot of headaches.

Alternatively you can use `std::hash` to generate you a better number that is less likely to clash (that use the module operator on that to get the actual index number).

#### Design of C++

You use `std::shared_ptr` to link all the elements in the list together. Personally I would have used a pointer (its self contained and you can control all the uses). But there is an argument for using a smart pointer (just not std::shared_ptr).

In this situation there is no sharing of the pointer. Each pointer is owned by exactly one parent. So use `std::unique_ptr` this will handle all the management of the pointer without the extra overhead needed by shared pointer.

#### Design of Interface

Your interface is `put/get/erase`.

The only big issue I see is the `get()`. What happens when you get a key that does not exist? You return a magic value (which is a bit of a code smell). How do you distinguish the magic value from a real value (do you prevent the magic value from being inserted?).

There is a small issue around `put()`. What happens if you put a key that already exists. Simply overwrite it? Sure that works. Might be nice to warn in this situation.

To me the `put/get` design has an issue for me in that it requires a two phase update. If I want to modify a key I first have to get the value associated with the key manipulate and then put the value back. In C++ we usually perform a retrieve from a container via a reference. That way once you have the value you can manipulate it directly. Also this makes it more efficient as you are not re-calculating the location using a hash and search on a list.

```
 int&  value = cont.get(23);
 value = value + 5; // update in place as we are using a reference.
```

It even looks really nice if you overload `operator[]` so it looks like a normal array accesses.

```
 int&  value = cont[23];
 value = value + 5; // update in place as we are using a reference.

 // Or simply
 cont[23] += 5;
```

### Code Review

I would have put this class as a private member of `HashMap`.

```
class HashEntry {}
```

It does not seem to be leaked by any of the `HashMap` interfaces (which is good) so it does not need to be exposed to the user. Also by making it private you can remove the `get/set` methods which are completely useless in this context.

Sure you can keep this simple first time and just use `int` as the key and value. But in C++ when we make containers we usually create them generically so anything can be the key or value. I would have a look at templates.

```
    int key_v;
    int val_v;
```

OK. You can use a smart pointer to manage this chain.

```
    // The smart pointer to handle multiple keys with same hash value.
    // This will be used to create a linkedlist.
    std::shared_ptr<HashEntry> next_v;
```

But `std::shared_ptr` is the wrong smart pointer. Use `std::unique_ptr`.

OK I see why you had to use `std::shared_ptr`. You don't use references anywhere in your code. Which means that all values are copied on return. `std::unique_ptr` is non copyable which would be an issue here. You still need to use `std::unique_ptr` but you need to return by reference to make this work.

```
    std::shared_ptr<HashEntry> next() const
```

Prefer to use the initializer list.

```
HashMap::HashMap(std::size_t capacity)
{
    capacity_v = capacity;      // put this in the initializer list.
    map_v.resize(capacity_v);
}
```

This function does not change the state of the container. You can also mark it const.

```
std::size_t HashMap::hash_func(int key)
{
    return key % capacity_v;
}
```

OK. You do need to search the list to see if it exists and over-right on a push (would be nice to know if I did over-right).

```
// The function to insert key-value pair
void HashMap::put(int key, int val)
{
        while(node)
        {
            if(node->key() == key)
            {
                node->set_val(val);
                return;
            }
            pre = node;
            node = node->next();
        }
```

**BUT** I think it is a bad idea to add to the end.

```
        pre->set_next(std::make_shared<HashEntry>(key, val));
```

There is a concept of locality of reference. If you have used something then you will probably use it again soon (or a value close it). So if you put the value at the front a subsequent get (or over-righting put) will not have to perform as long of a search. So I would put the new value at the beginning of the chain.

In this function:

```
// Retrieve value based on key
int HashMap::get(int key)
{
```

I am not sure why you have this extra `if statement`

```
    if(node->next() == nullptr && node->key() == key)
    {
        return node->val();
    }
```

Seems redundant to me.

Comment: Thank you for the reply (upvoted). Thank you for pointing out issues in the location of new entry in the list. The reason why I went with no warning for over-writes in `put` is because I didn't observe such behavior with `std::unordered_map`. I avoided templates to keep the first version simple.  Also, thank you for suggestions regarding use of prime numbers.

Comment: Regarding your first issue (size and capacity): Having a capacity, especially in this kind of hash map, is a good thing (unless you're fine with \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$ operations, instead of the expected \$\mathcal{O}(1)\$). If that capacity is reached, I'd suggest increasing the number of buckets and rehashing instead of throwing an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Good for the first try, but there are a lot of things to improve.

### Too many indirections

`std::shared_ptr` -> `std::unique_ptr`, because no multithreading is perceived in the usage cases, `std::unique_ptr` is much more lightweight, albeit being a little bit harder to use. It compiles down to safe code written by hand.

`std::vector<std::shared_ptr<HashEntry>>` -> `std::vector<HashEntry>`, because backwards links are not established anyway, and resizing is never done.

### Interface

Not generic (e.g. not a template).

I would rather return empty `std::optional` than print a message to `stdout`.

`HashEntry` should be private to the map.

I don't see any reason for `hash_func` to be public. It is not used outside of the class, nor is it stated that it is supposed to be used outside.

`get` should be const member too.

Doesn't provide any way to iterate over entire map.